# Counting automorphisms that preserve a group action

Tags: permutation, infinite-loop, group-theory

Note: the math, I believe, is not the problem here. The issue is not that I get the wrong answer, just that my code does not terminate. So, if you do not feel comfortable with the problem below, I do not believe it is necessary to diagnose the problem with my code.

The problem I am trying to solve (assuming you know some group theory) is

> For a group $G$, consider the automorphisms $(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$ on $G\times G\times G$ that have the following property: if $(a,b,c)\in G\times G\times G$ are such that $ab=c$, then $\sigma_1(a)\sigma_2(b)=\sigma_3(c)$ (under the group action of $G$). For $G=\mathbb{Z}_n$, count the number of such automorphisms.

The first function, `σ3`, takes the inputs `lines` (a list of all $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{Z}_n^3$ where $a+b\equiv c$), `σ1`, and `σ2` each in an ordered tuple of length $n$. It then applies via `rule1` and `rule2` the first two permutations, $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. These determine some $\sigma3$ by the property that $\sigma_1(a)+\sigma_2(b)\equiv\sigma_3(c)$ for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ (although it may not be a valid permutation). The function then outputs ordered pairs: $(c,\sigma_3(c))$ for each element in `lines`.

```
σ3[lines_List, σ1_List, σ2_List] := 

    Module[{rule1 = {}, rule2 = {}, lines1 = {}, lines2 = {}, 
        original = {}, image = {}, n = 0},

        n = Length[σ1];
        lines1 = lines;

        For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
            rule1 = 
                Map[If[#[[1]] == i - 1, # :> {σ1[[i]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}] &, 
                    lines] /. Null -> Sequence[];
            lines1 = lines1 /. rule1;
        ];

        lines2 = lines1;

        For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
            rule2 = 
                Map[If[#[[2]] == i - 1, # :> {#[[1]], σ2[[i]], #[[3]]}] &, 
                    lines1] /. Null -> Sequence[];
            lines2 = lines2 /. rule2;
        ];

        original = Map[#[[3]] &, lines];
        image = Map[Mod[#[[1]] + #[[2]], n] &, lines2];

        DeleteDuplicates[Partition[Riffle[original, image], 2]]
    ]
```

The second function the checks whether this is a valid permutation or not by checking the number of unique mappings of $c$ under $\sigma_3$ is the same as $\sigma_1$.

```
permCheck[lines_List, σ1_List, σ2_List] := 
    Length[σ3[lines, σ1, σ2]] == Length[σ1];
```

Finally, the function `znPerms` generates the list of $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{Z}_n^3$ such that $a+b\equiv c$ in the form of nested lists, generates a list of pairs of all possible permutations $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ (I know, crazy), and then, using `permCheck` and `σ3`, makes sure they generate a valid permutation $\sigma_3$. For each valid permutation, we increment `count` and then return `count`.

```
znPerms[n_] := Module[{lines = {}, allPerms = {}, count = 0},

    lines = 
        Select[Tuples[Range[0, n - 1], 3], 
            Mod[#[[1]] + #[[2]], n] == #[[3]] &
        ];

    allPerms = Tuples[Permutations[Range[0, n - 1], {n}], 2];

    For[i = 1, i <= Length[allPerms], i++,
        If[
            permCheck[lines, allPerms[[i, 1]], allPerms[[i, 2]]],
            count++;
        ];
    ];

    Return[count];
];
```

Although this is not feasible for many positive integers since the complexity grows on the order of $n!^2$ (I don't know if that's the correct wording), `znPerms[3]` should be fairly easy to compute as the list of pairs of all possible permutations is only of length 36. Alas, it does not terminate when executed.

I have tried encapsulating many parts of this code in `With` and testing it individually and everything seems to be working fine. It's only when it's all put together with `znPerms` that it gets stuck.

Any insight?

Comment: Like this? `t = Tuples[Permutations[{1, 2, 3}], 3];
gg = {0, 1, 2};
table = And @@@ (MapThread[
       Mod[gg[[#1]] + gg[[#2]], 3] == gg[[#3]] &, #] & /@ t);
Pick[t, table]`

Comment: Wow, if this works that's incredibly shorter. I have a rough idea of what the `table = And @@@`... line is doing but this produces the correct number of autmorphisms for $\mathbb{Z}_3$. I can't seem to generalize this to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: The problem is that the `Tuples[ ]` thing explodes quickly. Let me generalize it anyway.

Comment: With $n=4$, this returns the empty set, the problem I was having generalizing this. With $n=5$, it gives an error about running out of memory. I realize that the permutation we are checking is of size $5!^3=1728000$, but that still seems like a reasonable number for Mathematica to handle. I have 16 GB (13 GB free) of RAM and I believe that is the memory in question. I understand $n=10$ may be out of the question, but 5 seems feasible.

Comment: Something like `getAutomfsms[n_] := Module[{t, gg, table},
  t = Tuples[Permutations[Range@n], 3];
  gg = Range[0, n - 1]; 
  table = And @@@ (MapThread[
        Mod[gg[[#1]] + gg[[#2]], n] == gg[[#3]] &, #] & /@ t);
  Pick[t, table]
  ]

getAutomfsms[3]`. But yes, it is bruteforcing it, so it explodes very quickly

Comment: It seems like it should, but this does not work for $n=4$ for me.

Comment: mmmm ... I believe there is something wrong in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37549/discussion-between-gerald-and-dr-belisarius).